# Does ServiceStack 4 keep logs of the received HTTP request?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is there any log file automatically created and maintained by the ServiceStack web server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't log HTTP Requests by default but you can [register a Request Logger](https://docs.servicestack.net/request-logger) to enable it.